# Retrieving all descendants of an Id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, recursion, many-to-many, parent-child

I have a parent-child (many to many) table which holds `workgroup_id` and `parent_id` (a workgroup may have more than 1 parent).

I need to insert into a destination table all the descendants of each parent (i.e grandchildren, great grandchildren and so on), number of levels is unknow and can change.
For example my original table is:

```
wpwpr_workgroup wpwpr_parent
4   3
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   3
9   3
10  3
11  10
12  10
13  10
14  3
15  3
16  3
17  16
18  16
19  16
20  3
21  20
22  20
23  20
24  16
25  16
26  16
27  28
28  3
30  3
31  3
32  3
33  3
34  3
```

I need to  my destination table to look like this:

```
wpwpr_workgroup wpwpr_parent
10  3
11  3
12  3
16  3
17  3
18  3
11  10
12  10
17  16
18  16
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? I guess it will require some sort of recursion but I'm not quite sure how to go about this

Thank you very much
Regards
Zvi

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTE is probably the answer -- however it is messy if your structure can have multiple parents / circular ancestry.

You can also get a fairly efficient solution with a set based loop (each iteration of the loop does a parent search for the last set written and checks that the nodes don't already exist in the answer set.

If you post some more sample data we can probably give you some SQL to get you started.

Also -- what version of SQL Server are you using? CTE's are only available from 2005+

For the data you posted this will work:

```
    USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sample') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #sample
GO

CREATE TABLE #sample (
      wpwpr_workgroup INT
    , wpwpr_parent INT
    )
INSERT #sample (wpwpr_workgroup, wpwpr_parent)
VALUES
      (10,  3)
    , (11,  10)
    , (12,  10)
    , (16,  3)
    , (17,  16)
    , (18,  16)
GO

SELECT * FROM #sample

-- CTE
; WITH descendants AS (
    -- Anchor Definition
    SELECT wpwpr_workgroup AS [workGroup]
         , wpwpr_parent AS [Parent]
    FROM #sample
    -- Recursive Definition
    UNION ALL SELECT
        d.[workGroup] AS [workGroup]
         , s.wpwpr_parent AS [Parent]
    FROM
        descendants AS d
        JOIN #sample AS s ON s.wpwpr_workgroup = d.[Parent]
    )
SELECT * FROM descendants ORDER BY [workGroup], [Parent]
```

Results are:

```
workGroup   Parent
----------- -----------
10          3
11          3
11          10
12          3
12          10
16          3
17          3
17          16
18          3
18          16

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Hi Charlie Thanks for the quick response, i'm using SQL server 2008R2, I'm new in the field any chance you can show me a short code sample?

Comment: Done -- The recursive CTE's can get messy if you have circular ancestries. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: For someone new to SQL Server this is a pretty advanced topic. Read here to get the low down on CTE's: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thnks Charlie, seems to work exaclty like what6 i need, althogh i'll have to give it a deeper check against my table. I know how to use CTE's, just the concept of recursion is abit difficult for me to grasp. Again thanks a lot. Zvi